# robolectric memory leak due to numeorus ReceiverDispatcher and Activity instances

Tags: android, memory-leaks, robolectric

I'm writing unit tests for my company's project. Recently, our Jenkins builds started failing during unit test gradle task with `OutOfMemory` exceptions (caused by either `GC overhead` limit exceeded or `Java heap space`). On my local machine unit testing suceeds, but sometimes uses even 3.5 GB of memory. There are over 1000 tests in the project, hundreds of them create `Activity` instance.

I've took a heap dump (in a moment when about 1000 tests passed) and examined it with VisualVM. As both memory usage and heap size are constantly rising, I suspect there's a memory leak occurring somewhere.

I've run Eclipse Memory Analyzer with heap dump and #1 leak suspect are very numerous `ReceiverDispatcher` instances, about 255k of them (using > 500 MB of memory). Also, heap contains the same number of `IntentReceiverLeaked` instances, slightly more (258k) `shadowBroadcastReceiver` instances, and twice as less (about 127k) `AccessibilityManagerService` and `LockPatternUtils` instances.

This looks strange to me, because I found only one `BroadcastReceiver` being registered dynamically in the project (in `MainActivity`), and it's being properly unregistered in Activity's `onDestroy()` method.

Since there are about 300 Activity instances in the dump, I suspect leaking Activities as a main cause of the leak. Also, Eclipse Memory Analyzer lists `ShadowContextImpl` as a #2 problem suspect, with slightly more instances than Activities (but about 500 MB of memory used).

Activities in tests are created using `Robolectric.setupActivity()`, and relevant lifecycle methods are called on `tearDown()`

```
//Android Annotations are in use
protected ActivityController<MainActivity_> activityController;
protected MainActivity_ mainActivity;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    activityController = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity_.class).setup();
    mainActivity = activityController.get();
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    try {
        if (activityController != null) {
            activityController.pause()
                    .stop()
                    .destroy();
        }
    } catch (Throwable th){}

    mainActivity = null;
    activityController = null;
}
```

For Fragment-related tests, Fragment is created and attached to Activity in a regular way (instead of using FragmentTestUtil)

```
public static void startFragment(Fragment fragment, FragmentActivity activity) {
    shadowOf(Looper.getMainLooper()).pause();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(fragment, null);
    fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    shadowOf(Looper.getMainLooper()).runToEndOfTasks();
}

(...)    
Activity activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(MainActivity_.class);
MyFragment fragment = MyFragment_.builder().build();
startFragment(fragment, activity);
(...)
```

**What could be the cause of those leaks (and how to fix it) ? Could the way Activities and Fragments are initiated have something to do with the leak ?**

Comment: Hey Piotr, there is long-lived issue for it https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1700. And unfortunate it is not fixed yet. I would add your findings there

Comment: Thanks, I'll tell Robolectric team about this. Hope it'll help to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth - i've been trying to fix OOM errors when trying to migrate our app to RoboElectric 4.3 and AndroidX - Before going through and refactoring 2000 tests to make sure they finish and dispose of fragments and activities I could watch the gradle runner process in VisualVM max out it's available heap and the tests run slower and slower until they stopped or crashed with OOM errors

This got me back to work, adding this to the app build.grade:

```
 testOptions {
        unitTests {
            all {
                maxParallelForks = Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors()
                forkEvery = 100
            }
        }
}
```

means only 100 tests will get ran in a single process, so they never hit the heap size.